# Java Axis2 - Overriding HTTP Host Header

Tags: java, http, header, apache-axis, host

I need to override the HTTP "Host" Header value in a request sent using Axis2. The end goal is to send the HTTP request to a particular destination, while having the Host Header in the request read as something else.

I have looked this up and found that you can add custom headers, but the method used to do that will not allow you to override any.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html

Thanks!

Comment: the endpoint you are trying to hit is your destination/host? What you need to modify.

Comment: So...

There is a destination address in the TCP/IP header, and then the actual HTTP request (which is the body). I want to have the IP that the packet is being sent to be different than what is defined in the HTTP request Host Header.

Reason for this is because we are using a secure gateway to access our server.

Client -> Secure Gateway -> Server
The server will prevent access to some pages if the Host header of the HTTP request does not match that of the its URL.

I want the HTTP request sent to the Secure Gateway, while keeping the HTTP request Host header that of the Server.